# How to trigger onclick multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm trying to make a message pop up saying all changes have been saved, it works once, but then won't work a 2ed or 3rd time. code is below:

How can i make it work every time it is click?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".faChkRnd").on('click', function() {
     $("#result").html('All changes have been saved!');
     $("#result").addClass("alert alert-fmaj");
   });
   $("#result").fadeTo(4000, 500).fadeOut(1000, function() {
     $("#updateunit").alert('close');
   });
   $("#updateunit").submit(function() {
     return false;
   });
});

function clearInput() {
   $("#updateunit :input").each(function() {
     $(this).val('');
   });
}
```

And also tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".faChkRnd").on('click', function() {
     $("#result").html('All changes have been saved!');
     $("#result").addClass("alert alert-fmaj");
   });
   $("#result").fadeTo(4000, 500).fadeOut(1000, function() {
     $("#updateunit").alert('close');
     $("#result").removeClass("alert alert-fmaj"); 
   });
   $("#updateunit").submit(function() {
     return false;
   });
});

function clearInput() {
   $("#updateunit :input").each(function() {
     $(this).val('');
   });
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2xc1dk7e/)

Comment: Your click handler is being called, but you dont seem to reset your `#result` element (ie remove the `alert` classes, html, etc) so you wouldn't see a change

Comment: @Patrick Evans updated answer.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan  https://jsfiddle.net/2xc1dk7e/

Comment: You are doing the fadeIn/Out as soon as the document is ready, not after the click has happened. Move that code into the click handler

Comment: check out the jsfiddle, i did and no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reset the changes happen during the first show and hide of the alert div and move the `fadeTo` code inside the click handler, it will work. See this snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".faChkRnd").on('click', function() {
     $("#result").stop().html('').removeClass("alert alert-fmaj"); 
     $("#result").html('All changes have been saved!');
     $("#result").addClass("alert alert-fmaj in")
       .show().css('opacity',1);
     $("#result").fadeTo(1000, 500).fadeOut(1000, function() {
       //$("#updateunit").alert('close');
       $("#result").html('').removeClass("alert alert-fmaj"); 
     });
   });
   $("#updateunit").submit(function() {
     return false;
   });
});

function clearInput() {
   $("#updateunit :input").each(function() {
     $(this).val('');
   });
}
```

```css
.faChkRnd{margin-left:25px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox" id="like"> 
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox" id="like"> 
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox" id="like"> 
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="likebox" id="like"> 

<center><div id="result"></div></center>
```